# Play Market как выставить приложения

Tags: google-play, playmarket

Думаю вскоре мое первое приложения будет готово. Задумался как выставлять в Плей Маркет. Перешел на сайт и не понял 25$ один раз платишь при регистрации или за каждое приложения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Шаг очень неприятный. Вам нужно подарить 25 вечнозеленых чужому человеку. Чтобы вам было не так обидно, данную операцию назвали регистрационным взносом. Вам понадобится кредитная карточка с указанной суммой. Учтите, что Visa Electron, а уж тем более дисконтная карточка сети магазинов "Перекресток" вам не подойдут. Если у вас уже есть нужная карточка, то пропускаете этот абзац. Остальным могу посоветовать завести QIWI-кошелёк и там завести виртуальную карточку. Именно так я и поступил, так как идти в банк и писать всякие заявления было неохота.

Идём на страницу разработчиков, заполняем необходимые поля и расстаёмся с нужной суммой. Если операция пройдёт успешно, то вы сможете продвинуться дальше. В моем случае мне дважды отказывали, так как я пожадничал и положил на карточку меньшую сумму, чем требовалось (не учёл комиссию). Если вы позже доложили необходимую сумму, то не ждите, что её автоматически у вас спишут. Снова зайдите на страницу разработчика и отредактируйте данные о карточке (нужно еще раз написать код безопасности).

Answer (score 4):

25$ платится единоразово, потом можно выкладывать бесконечное число приложений.

Answer (score 0):

Взнос условно единоразовый - на 25 лет всего-то;)

Comment: А можно подтверждающую ссылку увидеть?

Comment: Уже нет, эта информация появляется при регистрации аккаунта разработчика и при оплате 25 уе. Там в окошке по дефолту стоит срок 25 лет. Или 20...